# Laravel 5.5 & Ajax : File upload not working contains fakepath

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have a form in gravity forms Wordpress, when I post I use Ajax and Laravel 5.5 API to get the post requests. When I post it works but I get "C:\fakepath\test.pdf" for the file upload.

When I use $request->file("input_54") in my controller, it returns null when I run a dd() the "input_54" is name of the input type file on my form and my gravity form does have "enctype= multipart/form-data" I use to upload.

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: data,
    success: function(response){
        console.log("It worked");             
    }
});
```

Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

public function formData(Request $request)
{
  dd($request->file("input_54"));
}
```